How to store Credentials in db?
I'm currently working on a project that utilizes dbAuth for user authorization. We're now faced with the requirement to integrate external data, which necessitates OAuth2.0 authentication for querying this data (distinct from the web login).
To illustrate, consider this scenario: a user logs into our platform using their platform-provided login credentials. Subsequently, they wish to integrate external data, such as a map service, utilizing OAuth2.0. Consequently, they input Request URL, Token URL, Secret, client ID, etc., into an interface and gain access to the desired data.
However, the challenge lies in securely storing these credentials. Ideally, each user would add their authentication methods to the database, which could then be utilized whenever necessary. Nonetheless, storing these secrets in plaintext in the database doesn't seem prudent.
Are there any methods to store these credentials in the database securely, without resorting to plaintext? Alternatively, is the concept fundamentally flawed, suggesting that credentials must be input each time the client wishes to utilize external data?
I would greatly appreciate any insights or opinions on this matter!
Thank you in advance!
